# How to merge two files if the buffer size is smaller than the size of the file?

Tags: c++, file, stl, merge, mergesort

How to merge two files if the buffer size is smaller than the size of the file?
For example, I have two files with sorted integers

1.txt  and  2.txt

```
2       1
5       7
6       8
7       9
```

I have to merge them in one sorted file but I can't read more than two numbers from each file(that's the task). And I cant have more than 4 numbers in memory at the same time.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int bufferSize = 2;

bool readSortFile(ifstream &file, vector<int> &data) {
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; (i < bufferSize && file >> tmp); i++)
        data.push_back(tmp);

    return file.good();
}

int main() {
    ifstream file1("1.txt");
    ifstream file2("2.txt");
    ofstream out;
    vector<int> data1, data2;
    bool fileGood1, fileGood2;

    fileGood1 = true;
    fileGood2 = true;

    while(fileGood1 || fileGood2) {
        if(data1.size() == 0)
            fileGood1 = readSortFile(file1, data1);
        if (data2.size() == 0)
            fileGood2 = readSortFile(file2, data2);

        out.open("temp", ios::app);
        merge(data1.begin(),
              data1.end(),
              data2.begin(),
              data2.end(),
              ostream_iterator<int>(out, "\n"));

        data1.clear();
        data2.clear();
        out.close();
    }
    rename("temp", "result.txt");
    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `1 2 5 7 6 7 8 9`

Comment: Have you looked at external sorting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting?

Comment: Have you tried to implement `merge`? The algorithm does not require that you keep the sources in memory, as a matter of fact it acts only on one value from each sequence... Alternatively you can just use the algorithm on your inputs directly by means of `std::istream_iterator` and `std::ostream_iterator`... just saying

Comment: Are the input files supposed to be already sorted ?

Comment: Like David said, `std::istream_iterator<int>` and `std::merge` would work pretty easily in concert to [solve this trivially](http://pastebin.com/XEc5ZBM7).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you only need 1 number from each file to implement a merge, but you'll probably need to write your own merge logic as opposed to using std::merge. Example pseudo code, you'll need to add eof checks (if end of 1.txt, copy rest of 2.txt and vice versa).

```
    num1 = get number from "1.txt"
    num2 = get number from "2.txt"
    loop(...){
        if(num1 <= num2){
            write num1
            num1 = get number from "1.txt"
        } else {
            write num2
            num2 = get number from "2.txt"
        }
    }
```